# quicker way for loop inside loop

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, exit

I have a working code for copying large amount of data from a monthly sheet to daily sheet. There are about 30 columns of data to be copied over 2000 rows. I don't know how I can speedup the job as it is taking about 3 minutes to copy even one column. I have to this for all 30 columns. The order of columns in monthly sheet is not same as in daily sheet; for eg. monthly sheet column D might represent column P of daily sheet. If the learned ones can help to improve the code I will be most grateful.

PJ

```
Sub COPY2()


Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, Lastrow2 As Long, myname As String
Dim SWB As Workbook, TWB As Workbook, Sws As Worksheet, Tws As Worksheet
Set SWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set Sws = SWB.Sheets("SHEET1")
Windows("DAILY.xlsX").Activate
Set TWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set Tws = TWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastrow1 = Sws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = Tws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sws.Activate
For i = 2 To lastrow1

myname = Sws.Cells(i, "B").Value

Tws.Activate
For j = 2 To Lastrow2

If Tws.Cells(j, "D").Value = myname Then Tws.Cells(j, "P").Value = Sws.Cells(i, "D").Value
If Tws.Cells(j, "P").Value = Sws.Cells(i, "D").Value Then Exit For


Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel operations take much time. Try to access data in blocks rather than cell by cell.
BTW activating sheets are useful while testing and debugging but it wastes your time when running the app live.

Try the snippet below. The concept is to read and manipulate data to buffers, and write back Excel in one single step when finished processing, so you can save thousends of Excel operations.

```
Dim sa(), tad(), tap()

lastrow1 = sws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastrow2 = tws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sws.Activate

sa = Range(sws.Cells(1, 2), sws.Cells(lastrow1, 4))     ' B:D columns
tad = Range(tws.Cells(1, "D"), tws.Cells(lastrow2, "D")) ' D column
tap = Range(tws.Cells(1, "P"), tws.Cells(lastrow2, "P")) ' P column


For i = 2 To lastrow1

    For j = 2 To lastrow2
    
         If tad(j, 1) = sa(i, 1) Then
             tap(j, 1) = sa(i, 3)
             Exit For
         End If
    
    Next j
Next i

Range(tws.Cells(1, "P"), tws.Cells(lastrow2, "P")) = tap

End Sub
```

Comment: AcsErno. All I can say that it is unbelievable!! Have to learn about this feature.